# Cannot read property 'cinemaName' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2 and above. I have defined a form with input type text as follow

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Cinema Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cinemaName" name="cinemaName" placeholder="Cinema Name" [(ngModel)]="addNewCinema.cinemaName">
                </div>
              </div>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
              <button type="submit" (click)="saveNewCinema()" class="btn blue-dark">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

in ts i have declared like this

```
addNewCinema:any = {  }
```

But when i try to run this am getting error like

`Cannot read property 'cinemaName' of undefined`

Comment: You'll have to show more of your `ts` file, there are no obvious issues in the code shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have not put your ts code in the right file, or it is not saved. With same above code, I am not getting any error.

Refer to my code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-331r8c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data in from an api do this:

```
[(ngModel)]="addNewCinema?.cinemaName"
```

The question mark is used if at runtime your template doesn't know what's coming up yet data wise.

Comment: The question stated `addNewCinema` is declared as such `addNewCinema:any = {  }`